# How do I design a database for information that does not YET have a schema?

Tags: database-design, blob

Say I want to build a database of emails. As I do not understand the structure of an email, I might store emails in a simple table with only basic attributes:

```
Emails
   email_id   integer (PK)
   from       varchar(200)
   sent       timestamp
   email      blob
```

But then later I decide that I understand the structure of an email after all and want to extend my database to represent the whole email as structured data instead of just a blob. I would probably create an EmailAddress entity, a MIME entity, a Header entity, with appropriate foreign keys and associative tables.

But what can I do in my database *now* in anticipation of one day unpacking a blob into a subschema?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a relational database for this.

Use a [document database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database), or some other [schemaless data store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

Comment: Are you saying to use a document database to store my schemaless data now, and then change my DBMS once I have a schema for the data?

Comment: @jl6 - No. I am saying to use the right tool for the job. Namely a document database.

Comment: But the nature of the question is that the job changes over time.

Comment: @jl6 - And when it does, you change the tools as required.

Answer (score 1):

Consider storing it in a structured format (e.g. XML) so that you can effectively convert the data to a proper format later.

Answer (score 0):

- Mask future schema changes by implementing an access layer. Use views for reading, stored procedures (or triggers) for writing to underlying tables -- avoid direct access from app layer to tables.
- Consider anchor modelling approach, which uses 6NF and is quite suitable for constant changes -- schema evolution. The anchor modelling toll automatically creates views and triggers as an access layer.